# wxPython is not available when running GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wxpython

When I run `python GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py` I get this message:

```
wxPython is not available
```

I have installed `wxPython` on my ubuntu 14.04 machine using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools wx2.8-doc wx2.8-examples wx2.8-headers wx2.8-i18n
```

and Python version is `Python 2.7.5`

Comment: Why exactly do you run this? the Google App Engine Launcher isn't suggested anymore. I would use gcloud if I was you.

Answer (score 0):

wxPython requires compiled code and thus is cannot be used with app engine.

I can't imagine how you would use wxPython with app engine anyway.  wxPython gives you a UI for programs that are downloaded and installed on to computers.  You may want to check out Bootstrap to help with a UI for your app engine app.

Comment: :wxPython is needed to open "GoogleAppEngineLauncher" UI.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.